# Port Android OS on PXA270 device

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux

I am working on WIN CE platform and quite new on Linux and android. I want to port android in PXA270 device running with ARM 9 processor. I googled and found, first install linux kernal, modify it according to the target device, add device drivers and install android image. Thats good but it is difficult for a new person like me. As i read somewhere that android is developed by modifying actual linux kernel(adding low memory killer, android logger etc) then why we dont use that modified android directly on our device. Is that available to use? If yes then how?
please tell... thnkx.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [0xdroid project](http://code.google.com/p/0xdroid/), they followed more or less the same route you want to take but for another platform (OMAP), nevertheless you'll probably learn some things from them and their project.

Maybe I'm wrong, but what you want to do looks like a major undertaking to me...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try the old Android porting for PXA27x:
    http://sourceforge.net/projects/android-pxa270/